# VBA Code: How would you count even numbers and add them up based off of a single user input box

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to count even numbers when there is string that has a minimum and a maximum this string is a user input string. For example:
[image]

- But if the user just enters a single number, then that becomes the max. For example:
  [image]

```
Sub AddupEvenNumbers2()
    Dim num As Variant
    Dim evennum As Long
    Dim sum As Double
    Dim str As String
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim max As String
    Dim min As String

    str = "Please enter the beginning number " & vbNewLine & "and maximum number (4 22) " & vbNewLine & "or just the maximum number (22) " & vbNewLine & "to get the total sum. "
    
    Do
        num = InputBox(str)
        
        If num Like "* *" Then
            min = Split(num)(0)
            max = Right(num, min)
        Else
            max = IsNumeric(num)
        End If
        
    Loop While IsNumeric(num)
    evennum = num
    sum = 0
    For evennum = min To max Step 2
        sum = min + max
    Next
    MsgBox "The sum of even numbers " & vbNewLine & "from " & min & max & vbNewLine & "is " & sum

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, no where does it talk about splitting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE below to fix error if min/max are not even - plus refactoring.

---

Your basic error is within you sum-routine: min + max is not what you want.
I fixed that error and improved the check of the input:

```vb
Sub AddupEvenNumbers2()
    Dim num As Variant
    Dim evennum As Long
    Dim sum As Double
    Dim str As String
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim max As Long
    Dim min As Long
    Dim fInputOK As Boolean

    Dim arrValues As Variant
    
    str = "Please enter the beginning number " & vbNewLine & "and maximum number (4 22) " & vbNewLine & "or just the maximum number (22) " & vbNewLine & "to get the total sum. "
    
    Do
        num = InputBox(str)
        If num = vbNullString Then Exit Sub 'cancel
        
        arrValues = Split(num)
        fInputOK = True
        
        'I improved the check for min and max value
        If num Like "* *" Then
            If IsNumeric(arrValues(0)) Then
                min = arrValues(0)
            Else
                MsgBox "wrong input"
                fInputOK = False
            End If
            If IsNumeric(arrValues(1)) Then
                max = arrValues(1)
            Else
                MsgBox "wrong input"
                fInputOK = False
            End If
        ElseIf IsNumeric(num) Then
            max = num
        Else
            MsgBox "wrong input"
            fInputOK = False
        End If
        
    Loop While fInputOK = False

    sum = 0
    For evennum = min To max Step 2
        sum = sum + evennum 'you have to add the evennum to the sum
    Next
    
    MsgBox "The sum of even numbers " & vbNewLine & "from " & min & " to " & max & vbNewLine & "is " & sum

End Sub
```

---

Update

```vb
Sub AddupEvenNumbers2()

    Dim maxUser As Long, minUser As Long
    
    If getMinMaxFromUser(minUser, maxUser) = True Then
    
        Dim min As Long, max As Long
        min = minUser: max = maxUser
        checkForEvenMinMaxValues min, max
    
        Dim sum As Long, i As Long

        For i = min To max Step 2
            sum = sum + i 'you have to add the evennum to the sum
        Next
        
        MsgBox "The sum of even numbers " & vbNewLine & "from " & minUser & " to " & maxUser & vbNewLine & "is " & sum
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub checkForEvenMinMaxValues(ByRef min As Long, max As Long)

'adjust this to your requirements

If min Mod 2 <> 0 Then min = min + 1
If max Mod 2 <> 0 Then max = max - 1

End Sub

Private Function getMinMaxFromUser(ByRef min As Long, ByRef max As Long) As Boolean

    Dim instruction As String
    instruction = "Please enter the beginning number " & vbNewLine & "and maximum number (4 22) " & vbNewLine & "or just the maximum number (22) " & vbNewLine & "to get the total sum. "

    Dim fInputOK As Boolean
    Dim answer As String, arrValues As Variant, i As Long
    
    Do
        answer = InputBox(instruction)
        If answer = vbNullString Then Exit Function 'cancel
        
        arrValues = Split(answer)
        
        For i = 0 To Application.min(UBound(arrValues), 1)
            If checkValidValue(arrValues(i)) = False Then GoTo askAgain
        Next
        
        fInputOK = True
        
        If UBound(arrValues) = 0 Then
            min = 0
            max = arrValues(0)
        Else
            min = arrValues(0)
            max = arrValues(1)
        End If
        
askAgain:
    Loop While fInputOK = False

    getMinMaxFromUser = fInputOK

End Function

Private Function checkValidValue(varValue As Variant) As Boolean
    If Not IsNumeric(varValue) Then
        MsgBox varValue & " is not a valid value.", vbExclamation
    Else
        checkValidValue = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: @TomBrunberg - you are right - quick answers are not always the best ones - I did an additional refactoring as well

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a function for calculating the sum of even numbers inside a closed interval [a,b]. a and b can be positive or negative.

```
Function SumEvenNumbersInterval(a As Long, b As Long) As Long
    Dim min As Long
    Dim max As Long
    
    max = a Xor ((a Xor b) And --(a < b))
    max = max - Sgn(max) * (max Mod 2)
    min = a Xor ((a Xor b) And --(a > b))
    min = min + Sgn(min) * (min Mod 2)
    
    SumEvenNumbersInterval = (max - min + 2) * (max + min) / 4
End Function
```

And a function for cleaning up a string and returning all numbers from it in an array

```
Function GetNumArray(inputString As String)
    With CreateObject("vbscript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[^0-9]+"
        GetNumArray = Split(Trim(.Replace(inputString, " ")))
    End With
End Function
```